# How to set Local Storage on Timer

Tags: javascript, timer

When I refresh page timer is reset. I would like to set localStorage on this timer, how do it set in localStorage

**HTML**

```
00 : <span id="timer">02 : 00</span>
```

**JavaScript** :-

```
window.onload = function() {
    var min = "0" + 2;
    var sec = "0" + 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        var a = new Date();
        var time = min + " : " + sec;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time;
        if (sec == 00) {
            if (min != 0) {
                min--;
                sec = 59;
                if (min < 10) {
                    min = "0" + min;
                }
            }
        } else {
            sec--;
            if (sec < 10) {
                sec = "0" + sec;
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Start by changing the interval function to display the difference between the current time and a timestamp. Then you can store that timestamp in local storage. The timestamp will be your end time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Local storage like this:

1- On windows `load` check if you have already local storage for variables `min` and `sec`, if yes get both values using `localStorage.getItem("item")` else set both variables to start values.

2- Inside `setInterval` make sure that you are updating both local storage for `min` and `sec` while updating those variables.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctxmv8c7/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 local storage feature.

```
<script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
</script>
```

Comment: dude u copy this coding from w3school i already try this and if any thing new then give idea okkkk